# How to detect screen location on UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, touch, gesture, tap

The App needs to get the screen location(x,y) when a UICollectionView cell is selected.

I had tried `touchesBegan`, but it fail to work. And I had also tested with `UITapGestureRecognizer` and `gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceiveTouch touch: UITouch) -> Bool`, when set it `true` or `false`, it works with either gesture or tapping on a cell, not both.

Any way to get the two actions work at the same time?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "either gesture or tapping"? What's the other gesture?

Comment: @beyowulf it means when gesture `shouldReceiveTouch` is set to true,  gesture get called and collection cell ` didSelectItemAtIndexPath` doesn't. When it's set to false, collection cell ` didSelectItemAtIndexPath` get called and gesture doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you need both of those to fire. Whatever you're doing in one you could just move that code to the other. But to answer you question you can do something like.

Don't use didSelectItemAtIndexPath. Move that code into the gestureRecognizer. If you need the indexPath for the tap say something like:

```
let tapLocation = gesture.location(in: self.view)
let indexPath = collectionView.indexPathForItem(at: tapLocation)
```

If you don't like that you can try implementing

```
optional func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer,
shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool
```

And returning true to see if that will allow both methods to be called.

Comment: The 2nd one doesn't work, but the first one works great! Thanks a lot!